# Parse double from JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, regex, swing, jformattedtextfield

I've got a bug or something. I have a method that saves an article, like this:

```
  class SaveArticleListener implements ActionListener {
    //....
    String s = textArticlePrice.getText().replace(',','.').replaceAll("\\s","");
    double price = Double.parseDouble(s);
    //....
}
```

Where `textArticlePrice` is a `JFormattedTextField` which configured like:

```
NumberFormat priceFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
priceFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
priceFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
textArticlePrice = new JFormattedTextField(priceFormat);
textArticlePrice.setColumns(10);
```

And in the `parseDouble` method I'm getting every time:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123 456 789.00"
```

So `replace` works with a dot, but not with whitespace... Why?

Comment: Can you show us your `parseDouble`?

Comment: Also, what does `textArticlePrice.getText()` return in your ActionListener?

Comment: @tieTYT oh, sorry. it's a static import from Double class

Comment: @tieTYT it returns a string which has only digits, whitespaces and one comma, which a should replace properly and pass to the parseDouble method

Comment: mind pasting an example of that?  Perhaps grab it from the debugger.

Comment: First, print the `s` variable after replaceAll().

Comment: @tieTYT i've debugged this for a time and this is where i came. if you mean some tools im not that qualified for a moment.

Comment: @DávidHorváth I wrote it already - "123 456 789.00". replaceAll() is the last method i'm calling before parseDouble, so in exception message you see argument which is `s`.

Comment: Second, print `textArticlePrice.getText()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using your `NumberFormat` to parse the `String`. Keep a reference to `priceFormat`, and then use

```
double price = priceFormat.parse(textArticlePrice.getText()).doubleValue();
```

The formatter that's being used to display the number is the same one then used to turn it back into a `double` so you know it's going to be parsing it in a compatible way.

Best of all is

```
double price = ((Number) textArticlePrice.getValue()).doubleValue();
```

which should work without any need for conversion if you've set your `JFormattedTextField` up properly. (The `getValue()` call returns an `Object`, so you need to cast it. It might return a `Double` or a `Long`, depending on what's in the text field, so the safe way to get a `double` out of it is to treat it as a `Number`, which is the supertype of both, and invoke its `.doubleValue()` method.)

Writing something that converts it into something that can be parsed by `Double.parseDouble()` is really not the right way to go because it's too fragile if the formatting of your text field changes later on.

Comment: thanks, that's works. nice solution, but is there any mistakes in my code ?

Comment: @Mark If you mean in the other bit of your code that sets up the `JFormattedTextField`, it looks fine to me!

Comment: `(Double) textArticlePrice.getValue()` isn't working for situation when user types number without fraction (which is strange, because in UI formatter adds ",00"), then i get `ClassCastException`, because actual type is Long, so i need to call parseDouble then.

Comment: @Mark I've edited it slightly to allow for that case. It will always return a `Number` (because that's the supertype of all number types), and `Number` has a `.doubleValue()` method that gives you the value as a `double` even if it started life as a `Long`.

Comment: oh, that's also looks nice :) well, think this is all i need, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question" why doesn't it work with white spaces". White spaces are chars just like a,l,#,?,¡, but it only recognises ,12345, numbers together as a number, you cant make an int variable 'int number = 1 234; Its the same with parsing. Rather try,

```
s = s.replace(',','.');
s = s.replace(" ","");
Price = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Assuming that '123 456 789.00' is one number.

please comment if this helped.

Comment: thanks for answear. i've tried that way before replacing it with regex(\\s) and it doesn't seems to work either

Comment: regex? And I litterally just coded it now. The example 123 456 789.00 looked strange because the number is too long.

Answer (score 0):

I did this now, it worked fine

```
String strNumber = "1 2 3 4 5 6.789";
double DblNumber = Double.parseDouble(strNumber);
System.out.Println(DblNumber);// this displays the number if your IDE has an output window
```